# Should British Virgin Islands be listed as British Virgin Islands or United Kingdom in the N-400 travel history?

Tags: usa, citizenship, paperwork, british-virgin-islands

One has to indicate in the travel history in the [N-400 Application for Naturalization Form](https://www.uscis.gov/n-400) ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20200716010951/https://www.uscis.gov/system/files_force/files/form/n-400.pdf?download=0)). If I went to the British Virgin Islands, should British Virgin Islands be listed as British Virgin Islands or United Kingdom in the N-400?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The British Virgin Islands are not part of the United Kingdom, so you should mark them as a separate country